# Unable to center h1 after adding a second element using display: inline;

Tags: html, css

In my current application (photo below), I am trying to add a button to navigate back. But the button needs to be on the line as the h1. The problem is, after adding the button, my CSS property for the h1 `text-align: center` moves to the right, because of the new button I added.

[image]

What can I do to make the h1 centered again?

```css
.backButton {
  margin-top: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.titleAndBackButton {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="titleAndBackButton">
  <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-arrow-left" class="p-button-outlined backButton"></button>
  <h1>Edit Your Category</h1>
</div>
```

I am very grateful for every help offered!

Comment: It is not centered because you added a `margin-left: 25%;` to the containing div

Comment: Try using flexbox instead of `float`

Comment: your container says display: inline; but your H1 is display: block;, the display style does not work on children. make your H1 display: inline-block. Also what T J says, use flexbox.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include an [mcve] snippet of the issue, to better enable the community to assist you?  Additionally, if you could include a screenshot or clear description of the desired behavior it would be useful, as there seems to be some confusion in the answers...

Answer (score 2):

This is a **crude** solution based on your code, and I advise using `flex`, `grid` or `absolute` positioning.

You use `margin-left: 25%` for a `.backButton` selector. For this reason, the `h1` tag is discarded.
Use rule `left` in conjunction with rule `position: relative`. Remove `margin-left: 25%`, and add these css rules to the `.backButton` selector:

```
position: relative;
left: 25%;
```

Use rules `left`, `position: relative` and `transform: translateX(50%)` for tag `h1` using rule `float: right`. Add these rules to tag `h1`:

```
float: right;
position: relative;
left: -50%;
transform: translateX(50%);
```

```css
.titleAndBackButton {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.backButton {
    margin-top: 40px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="titleAndBackButton">
    <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-arrow-left" class="p-button-outlined backButton"></button>
    <h1>Edit Your Category</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use {position: absolute} and then center it

Comment: I definitely wouldn't recommend using position absolute to center the `h1`; _maybe_ you could use it on the arrow button to keep it out of the document flow and stuck to the left.

Comment: I don't see why not, its an option, and it has been suggested by other users as well